# How to populate a vector of vector of set from file?

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, vector, set

I have a 3x3 matrix into my txt file with some numbers and some zeroes like this

```
0 0 3
1 0 0
0 2 0
```

I want to read it as a vector of vectors of sets. And where I have zeroes I want to populate that cell with numbers 123. Like

```
1231233
1123123
1232123
```

I would like to know if I print it correctly.

I've written this code:

```
class Matrix {
  private:
    vector<vector<set<int> > > cell;
  public:
    Matrix(const string& filename)  {
        ifstream file("matrix.txt");
        if (!file.good())   {
                cerr<<"Error";
            }

        int x;
        int y;
        for(x=0; x<3; x++)  {
            for(y=0; y<3; y++)  {
              for(vector<vector<set<int> > >::iterator it = cell.begin(); it != cell.end(); it++)   {
                if(file != 0)   {
                 cell[x][y] = file; // Don't think this part of code is good because I get error here
                }   else    {
                   int z;
                   for(z = 1; z<4; z++) {
                     cell[x][y].insert(z);
                     cout<<cell[x][y];  // Of course I get an error here too.       
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is that iteration of useful for somewhat? I'm not using "it" anywhere but I think that into a set I have to use it.

Of course something is not correct or is missing but I'm not understanding what and why.
I have to use vectors and sets.

I would prefer printing it to know if I do it well.

**Edit**
Trying to write file>> cell[x][y];
gives me this error: [Error] cannot bind 'std::basic_istream' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream&&'.

Comment: `cell[x][y] = file;` --> `file >> cell[x][y];`? Please make a [mre] e.g what is `cell`?

Comment: You have a two-dimensional matrix - a `vector<vector<int>>` would be a reasonable data type to store it in - you don't need `set` in there as well.

Comment: You are right @TonyDelroy but then I will have to work on those sets to delete some numbers from that

Comment: Again, what is `cell`?

Comment: Updated `cell` declaration and error given due to `file>>cell[x][y];`

Comment: Cell[x][y] is a set of integers. Youd need to provide a stream extraction operator overload thatt takes a set of integers to be able to do file >> cell[x][y].

Comment: @PedroBoechat Could you please explain it answering? I don't know if I'm understanding.

Comment: Here's what I meant by providing a stream extraction (and also stream insertion) operator overload: https://onlinegdb.com/H1p8xUkvD. I tried not to deviate from your (bad) design decisions too much (like using vectors and sets :)). I expect you to be able to extrapolate from my example.

Comment: @PedroBoechat Thank you a lot. I guess that it's bad design but I don't understand very well why. Could you please explain me why is it?

Comment: The principle is simple: aways avoid paying for things you are *not* going to use. If you don't need to dynamically reallocate your array (i.e., your matrix), use a statically allocated one (like array, as @VladFeinstein suggested, or at least pre-allocate the memory). If you are going to directly access your cell items (i.e, access them by index), don't use a tree-like structure like set. Also, if you use set you're paying for sorting your cell items, which might be even undesirable if you want to keep insertion order. The principle is rather simple but you gotta learn your data structures...

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me: you might want to keep your entire matrix in a contiguous block of memory to help your CPU to access stuff faster, and by using a vector of vectors you have no guarantee that this is what is going to happen. So, if you know the size of your matrix/grid and the number items on your cell, try to allocate a big chunk of memory in which they would all fit together (e.g.: int matrix[NumRows * NumCols * CellSize]);

Comment: Ok thank you for explaining all. I want to use a set into two vectors because I have to find and delete some elements into it. So I have to do it because I'm not able to access and delete a precise element with vectors. For now I'm not preallocating memory in vector declaring their dimension but I will do it because you're all saying that is better. However if you are thinking that I'm wrong please tell me because I would like to learn more.

Comment: If you think you're going to frequently delete/add your cell items/elements, then think about using a linked-list (std::list). If you're going to be reading/accessing your cell items/elements much more frequently then deleting/adding them, then consider using a special value (e.g., std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), if you can afford to lose 1 value, ofc) to represent a deleted item/element (i.e., the value -2147483648 would mean that this element was deleted).

Comment: Yeah I know my inital dimension, but after running the program I will have to access and delete cell elements until I have only one of them for every cell. So my final dimension will be smaller than initial one. Btw I'll keep in mind to use lists.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your vector of vectors, but they all are empty; you can't access any of the elements by their index. You may want to resize them to `3` elements each.

If you know that they are `3x3`, just use `std::array`:

```
std::array< std::array<std::set<int>, 3>, 3> cell;
```

Also, `set` doesn't implement operator `<<`, so you have to do it yourself (with a loop):

```
cell[1][2].insert(7);
cell[1][2].insert(13);
for(auto x: cell[1][2])
  std::cout << x;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Same for operator `>>`:

```
int val(0);
std::cin >> val;
cell[1][2].insert(val);
```

P.S. You have too much going on in the `Matrix`'s constructor. What if the file `"matrix.txt"` doesn't exist? Or is badly formatted? You'd have an object that is not valid, so to use it you'd need to immplement something like `valid()` method. It will be better to construct an empti matrix and load it in a different method, like `load()`.

Here is how you can use vectors, load and print:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::set<int>>> cell(3, std::vector<std::set<int>>(3));
// load from file
int val(0);
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    file >> val;
    cell[x][y].insert(val);
    }
}

// print
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    for (auto it = cell[x][y].begin(); it != cell[x][y].end(); it++)
      std::cout << *it;
    }
}
```

This, of course, prints nothing as the sets are empty. You can read into those sets like I did above.

Comment: What if I would like to use vectors? Can I declare it with: `vector<set<int> > row = vector<set<int> >(3);` and then  `vector<vector<set<int> > > cell = vector<vector<set<int> > >(3, row);` Should it work?   Can I print using iterator as I did in my code? (and using `std::cout`) What about reading that matrix from file?

Comment: I updated it, sorry but I didn't write it because I didn't want to write too much unuseful code for asking my question

Comment: And how can I read that matrix from file storing already existing numbers in those sets?

Comment: See another update. However, I've already showed to you how do load individual cells in the beginning of my answer.